# Как добавить элемент в список в с++? Как создать список в с++?

Tags: c++, рекурсия

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int i;
  cin >> i;
  int rec(i,l) {
    if ((i - 1) >= 0) {
    cout << (i - 1);

    i -= 1;
    return rec;
    } 
  else {
    return l;
    }
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Задача такова нужно вывести все числа, до какого-то а. Циклы использовать нельзя.

На питоне будет примерно так:

```
a = int(input("a = ")) #создаём переменную
l = [] #создаю список
l.append(a) #добавляю а
def rec(a, l): #создаю функцию
 if (a - 1) >= 0:
  l.append(a - 1) #добавляю элемент в список
 a -= 1
 return rec
else:
 return l #возвращаю список
```

как реализовать добавление элемента в список в с++?

Comment: Если вы создадите список - то как будете выводить его без цикла? Не то чтобы это было невозможно :), но просто интересен ход ваших мыслей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Именно **вывести**? тогда зачем вам список?

```
void out(int n, int curr = 0)
{
    if (n < curr) return;
    cout << curr << endl;
    out(n,curr+1);
}
```

На всякий случай - а то вы стали создавать вложенные функции :( - вот [весь код](https://ideone.com/YlzenY):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void out(int n, int curr = 0)
{
    if (n < curr) return;
    cout << curr << endl;
    out(n,curr+1);
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int m, M;
    cout << "From: "; cin >> m;
    cout << "To  : "; cin >> M;

    out(M,m);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе, постараюсь в этом разобраться. Ты сделал всю работу за меня. Спасибо

Comment: а разве рекурсивный вызов не является циклом?

Answer (score 1):

Если имеется ввиду стандартный список, то так:

```
std::list<int> l; // создание списка
l.push_back(a - 1); //добавление элемента в конец списка
```

Comment: Думаю автор немного удивится, когда не сможет получить доступ к элементу через [ ] :), всё же добавьте в ответ vector

Comment: ну я сначала было написал vector, но потом подумал, что раз уж список, то пусть будет список. Автор должен также думать, задавая вопрос.

Comment: всё же список в питоне не то же самое, что список в c++, на более низком уровне он устроен, вроде как, динамический массив указателей, т.е. как вектор

Comment: ну я всё равно считаю это проблемой автора, то что он не удосужился поинтересоваться структурами данных, говорит скорее о том, что это вопрос рода напишите мне готовый код. Поэтому я привёл именно то, что он просит, чтобы он сам разобрался в вопросе. Можете добавить другой ответ, если считаете мой ответ некорректным.

Comment: Beaver Feller, помимо вектора есть еще deque